# How far should shingles hang over the drip edge of the roof?

Tags: roof, roofing, shingles, asphalt

Is it normal for asphalt shingles to hang past the drip edge a couple of inches on the rakes of the roof?
[image: Shingles protruding past dripedge]

Comment: Not only will that sag severely once it gets warm, it's crooked as all get-out. Shoddy for sure.

Comment: Typically they hang out far enough so that water running off does not adhere (due to its surface tension) as it rolls over the top edge. Pour some water from a cup or glass at a decently quick speed on the roof there to see if it is adhering to the underside. If it is, then the shingles need to stick out more. If it is not, then they are sticking out enough. It's hard to tell without a frame of reference but this looks like it's sticking out a half inch to an inch, which should be plenty.

Comment: Can you provide a photo from an angle above the shingles as well? And how long has this roof been in place? Is it a newly-installed roof? Also, what is your specific concern here? Looks? Water displacement? Material integrity?

Answer (score 16):

It may depend on the specific brand and version of the shingles used.  Here is an advisory from GAF a major manufacturer:

[GAF Shingle Advisory](https://www.gaf.com/en-us/document-library/documents/documents/technicalbulletinsdocuments/residentialenglishdocuments/R__141_Drip_Edges_and_Shingles.pdf)

In it they say:

> Shingles should not extend more than 3/4” (19 mm) past the drip edge.
> If shingles overhang the edge of the roof by more than 3/4” (19 mm),
> then they are not supported and may crack and break off. In addition,
> the wind resistance at the roof edge may be compromised.

Here is another manufacturer's information from:

[Owens Corning Installation](https://dcpd6wotaa0mb.cloudfront.net/mdms/dms/Roofing/10022496/10022496-Drip-Edge-Installation-Technical-Bulletin.pdf?v=1628575559000)

Which says:

> Asphalt shingles should overhang the exterior edge of the drip edge by
> ¼ to ¾-inch.

Comment: Thank you for referring to the manufacturer’s recommendation instead of saying “I’ve been doing this for 30 years and I’ve   never had a problem.”

Comment: @LeeSam - I'd take the word of a 30yrs experienced artisan over manufacturer's recommendation all day long! That's a lot of trial and error!

Comment: @Tim  If you do, you’ll loose you guarantee and any replacement costs they would have paid. That’s why we say: follow the manufacturer’s recommendation AND use all the material from that manufacture. That way they can’t point the finger and say: it’s not our fault. My dad use to say: General Motors designs them, they build them, they test them, you better follow their maintenance schedule.

Comment: @Tim Experience is good, to be sure, right up to the point where it contradicts the people who made the thing. Then it's not experience, but hubris. Products and methods change all the time, especially in the building industry. And the sub-field of building _science_ is still quite new, but has already drastically changed how we think about so many aspects of building.

Comment: @Tim often "artisans" take liberties for "artistic" purposes. i.e. Form over function. Also, just because someone has been doing something for 30 years doesn't mean he's either _competent_ or an "artisan". I've known people (in all sorts of industries) who have been doing crap work for decades. I don't take their advice.

Answer (score 0):

I just had my roof done and they hung them over about 1.5 inches and the installer said they trained us to extend them to reduce ice getting under them in Snow and ice areas In the Northeast